# Calculate average sleep for python threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm simplifying what I'm trying to achieve as much as possible
I have the following script:

```
import time, urllib, random
import threading

def get(timeout):
    for i in range(2):
        time.sleep(timeout)
        return urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:9855').read()

def calculate_timeout(total_threads):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    total = random.randint(0,400)
    for i in xrange(total):
        threading.thread(target=get, kwargs={"timeout":calculate_timeout(len(total)}).start()
```

What I need to do is modify the `calculate_timeout` function in such a way so that whatever random number comes up,
there won't be more than 60 urllib requests per minute on average.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bevy of rate limiting algorithms posted [here](https://gist.github.com/gregburek/1441055) including examples for threaded code, the simplest 'imo' I've posted below. The code will create a decorator which you can then use to decorate your `get` method with.

```
import time
import threading

from functools import wraps


def rate_limited(max_per_second):
    """
    Decorator that make functions not be called faster than
    """
    lock = threading.Lock()
    min_interval = 1.0 / float(max_per_second)

    def decorate(func):
        last_time_called = [0.0]

        @wraps(func)
        def rate_limited_function(*args, **kwargs):
            lock.acquire()
            elapsed = time.clock() - last_time_called[0]
            left_to_wait = min_interval - elapsed

            if left_to_wait > 0:
                time.sleep(left_to_wait)

            lock.release()

            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
            last_time_called[0] = time.clock()
            return ret

        return rate_limited_function

    return decorate
```